# how to show ValidationError in sweetalert2

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I am using [sweetalert2 v7.0.0](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and I am trying to show an error if the amount field is empty.

When I enter an amount on the first try it works without problem.

When I leave the field empty on the first try I get a validation error. After that when I write an amount and click submit button validation error doesn't disappear. it get stuck doesn't validate the second time. Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kjjnewbc/4/). I would appreciate if you can show me the way. Where I am doing wrong?

```
<a href="#" class="refundbutton"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Refund</a>

$(".refundbutton").click(function(){
    swal({
      title: 'Enter Refund Details',
      html:'<label for="ipt" class=" control-label"><span class="oval">1</span> Select refund type</label><select class="form-control refund_type"><option value="4"> Credit Card </option> <option value="5"> Cash </option></select>' +
      '<label for="ipt" class=" control-label"><span class="oval">2</span> Enter refund amount</label><input type="text" class="form-control nDiscount_fixed" autocomplete="off" style="height: 34px;" value="">',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
          preConfirm: function (value) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            if ($(".nDiscount_fixed").val() === "") {
              swal.showValidationError(
                'please enter a refund amount.'
              )
            }
             resolve([ $('.refund_type').val(), $('.nDiscount_fixed').val() ]) 

        })
      }
    }).then(function (result) {
    var swalrebateamount = parseFloat($('.nDiscount_fixed').val()).toFixed(2);

    if (swalrebateamount !="" && swalrebateamount !="0" ) { 
    //some code
    } 
    }).catch(swal.noop)
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reset validation error. [more details](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)

```
    if ($(".nDiscount_fixed").val() === "") {
              swal.showValidationError(
                'please enter a refund amount.'
              )
    }
    else
    {
           swal.resetValidationError();
    }
```

Comment: I have missed that method. Thank you very much. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Thank you! I have a diff problem also: the swal `confirmButton` becomes disabled (or turns into loader if i have `showLoaderOnConfirm: true`) and stays that way even though I used `swal.showValidationError` and didn't resolve the promise. Any ideas?

Comment: Now it's showValidationMessage and resetValidationMessage functions